# What is a "diploma mill"?

Tags: education, degree, cheating

I recently deleted a response on Academia.SE because many people thought my response was supporting the idea of a 'diploma mill'.  My understanding of the matter was that a diploma mill is simply a business that provides a piece of paper, and possibly some kind of shady verification service, for a fee.  That's it.  Money in, diploma out.   This does not seem to be the case for many of this community, however.

I've done a bit of research, cursory to be fair, and the most clearly defined line that I can find between a "real" school and a "fake" school is that of regional accreditation.  Beyond that it appears to be a subjective melange of opinions, ultimately boiling down to the idea of 'second class schools'.  Clearly, I am out of touch with the general consensus on this matter so I put it to you SE.

**What are the defining characteristics of a 'diploma mill'?**

Comment: In addition to my response, I wanted to add that I think you had the correct definition all along--although the academic standards at legitimate for-profit schools could be questionable, they are definitely not the same as diploma mills.

Comment: Judging from what I have heard from many different people, the definition of "diploma mill" is "a school that I feel is not as good as the one *I* attended". So, for Harvard graduates, Penn State and UCLA are "diploma mills". For Penn State and UCLA grads, ITT Tech and DeVry are "diploma mills". For ITT Tech and DeVry graduates, a "diploma mill" is an unaccredited school that requires actual coursework or exams. For graduates of unaccredited schools, a "diploma mill" is an institution that mails out automatic diplomas in exchange for cash payments without requiring any work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We should start with the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_mill):

> A diploma mill (also known as a degree mill) is an unaccredited higher education institution that offers bogus academic degrees and diplomas for a fee. These degrees may claim to give credit for relevant life experience, but should not be confused with legitimate prior learning assessment programs.

If a student doesn't have to do any academic work for a degree, or the student is given credit based on "life experience," it qualifies as a diploma mill.  Another key indicator is whether there are actually any *teachers* that work for the business.  While it is probably not illegal in most cases to claim a degree from such a company (and I deliberately do not use the term "institution"), there have been [many cases](http://www.earnmydegree.com/online-education/learning-center/fake-degree-disasters.html) of employees being disciplined or fired for using the degree to either get a job or to obtain a higher salary based on claiming a degree from a diploma mill (esp. teachers whose salaries are based on the level of a degree).

As the Wikipedia article notes, there are legitimate schools that have a system for awarding credit based on other formal education, such as military education obtained while on active duty or in the reserves (see, for instance, [this guide to transferring credit](http://www.acenet.edu/news-room/Pages/Military-Transfer-Guide.aspx)).  This type of credit transfer is rare for graduate work, although certain rigorous post-baccalaureate programs in the military, such as the [U.S. Navy's Nuclear Power School](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Power_School), may qualify for some post-B.S. programs.  This type of credit should not be confused with work obtained at the military's post-graduate schools, such as the [Naval Postgraduate School](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Postgraduate_School) or the [Air Force Institute of Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Institute_of_Technology).

Diploma mills should also not be confused with for-profit education, such as the infamous [University of Phoenix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Phoenix).  Arguments over the merits of for-profit education are not really within the scope of academia.stackexchange, but for what it's worth, degree-granting institutions of this type do require students to follow a curriculum, take actual classes (many times online), and give grades based on assessed performance (and charge a good bit of money per credit-hour).

Bottom line: if you have to pay a nominal fee for a "degree" that requires no official classes or research, you got your degree from a diploma mill.

Comment: Great response, Chris.