# Is a PhD from a developing country worth paying for?

Tags: phd, job-search, united-states, europe, developing-countries

In my country, Egypt, some well-known institutes offer PhD degrees. I want to apply for a PhD program in biostatistics for which I will certainly pay a lot of money.

How much would such a program increase my chances of joining academia in the USA or Europe?

---

EDIT: The OP didn't specify, and possibly doesn't know, whether the university in question is a [diploma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_mill) [mill](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/what-is-a-diploma-mill). To keep the question open, please assume that it is *not;* i.e., assume that the university is legit. If anyone is interested in whether it's worth obtaining a non-legit degree I recommend [starting a new question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If the OP wishes to clarify later on he should simply remove this note.

Comment: _Is a PhD...worth paying for it?_ --- No.

Comment: @JeffE Are there any free alternatives to help me join academia in US or Europe ? Background: I am a doctor. I've a good statistical and programming practice e.g. watched MOOCs, played with R software. but I don't have a degree in either statistics or computer science.

Comment: @JeffE Most PhDs cost a ton of money (in opportunity cost)?  Just because you did not pay tuition, does not mean it was free.

Comment: @emory my guess is that Jeff implies that, strictly from a monetary perspective,  a PhD is a bad investment regardless of whether you pay tuition or not.

Comment: Is a diploma mill PhD worth paying for? If it can move you from a place where human rights violations are routine to a place where they are rare? **ABSOLUTELY YES.  It is worth a lot of money.** Can Egyptian PhDs do that? I don't know, but doubt it.

Comment: You could also try to do a PhD in Europe or USA (and getting a salary for it). Since you are a doctor, a common alternative around here is to get a clinical position and do your PhD research alongside (provided your degree is recognised, of course).

Comment: @JeffE Without evidence to the contrary, I would assume that the question means, "Is the financial cost of getting a legitimate PhD worth it?" not, "Is it worth buying a PhD from a diploma mill?" And if you are saying that the financial cost of getting a legitimate PhD isn't worth it, that needs much more than two characters to explain.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you asking about the financial cost of getting a legitimate PhD from a legitimate university, or about the cost of buying a worthless scrap of paper from a diploma mill?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think the question was "Is a PhD from an Egyptian institute worth the cost given the OP's goals?".  It does not matter if they are diploma mills or not.

Comment: @emory Of course it matters. If the question is about Egyptian universities, answering it requires knowledge of those universities. If the question is about diploma mills, the answer is an immediate and unconditional no.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Research into those Egyptian institutes will probably reveal them to be diploma mills.  The practical question is will they help with visas, work permits, and in getting a job at some low tier US or European university.

Comment: High institute of public health at Alexandria university,Egypt uses credit hours system(so I think it's not a diploma mill). It provides a master degree followed by a Doctoral degree(master degree is a must for the Doctoral degree). It's a long path. That's why I am asking is it worth money and effort. The professors don't have multiple 'international' publications(with rare exceptions).

Comment: @emory No. The phrase "[diploma mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diploma_mill)" has a very specific meaning. It does not mean "bad university": it means "organization that will sell you a 'degree certificate' without you being required to do anything more than pay for it." Please do not use the phrase "diploma mill" to mean anything else.

Comment: @ahmedmar Since you mention the High Institute of Public Health in Alexandria, Egypt, [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2636300/) is a short write-up by the (U.S.) NIH about that school. It seems to specialize in health-related topics of interest to developing countries, and is the "the centre for progress in health development" in that region. Googling the school, I find several Fulbright scholars have studied there. It is possible that as a student there you would have the chance to network with scholars from all over the world. It's up to you to make a name for yourself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35682/discussion-on-question-by-ahmedmar-is-a-phd-from-a-developing-country-worth-payi).

Answer (score 32):

I don't think it's possible to give an answer in the abstract.  In general I wouldn't recommend paying a lot for a Ph.D. program anywhere, but it depends on how much they charge and how much money you have.  Ph.D. programs in developing countries vary enormously in quality and reputation, and how useful they would be for getting an academic job in the U.S. or Europe varies accordingly.

However, you can try to estimate this for the programs you care about.  The key question is how many Ph.D. recipients from these programs get jobs you would like.  Typically you can find lists of former students on a potential advisor's website, and some web searches will reveal what became of them.  (If you can't find any information on someone online, then they probably didn't get an academic job.)  If very few former students have jobs you would like, then that's a bad sign, while it's a good sign if many of them do.  Of course there are no guarantees either way, but this will give some context for how plausible different outcomes are.

Comment: " Typically you can find lists of former students on a potential advisor's website": typically in the US, maybe, but definitely not everywhere. There are tons of advisors who don't list former students (I'm one of them).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano you can do the same thing in reverse.  look on the web pages of the kinds of institutes you would like to join and see where their faculty got their PhDs.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano _There are tons of advisors who don't list former students (I'm one of them)._ — Why don't you?

Comment: @JeffE There are several reasons. First, it's totally uncommon in my field: even large groups don't list former members in their websites, and sometimes even current members. Thus, I don't see what benefit would come to me and my former students by listing them. In particular, if I am to list someone on a web page, I'd want to be able to tell them which benefits they would got out of that. Thus far, none of my students had an issue in finding a job, in industry or academic, upon graduation: what would be the benefit for them in being listed as former students of mine? None.

Comment: As for me, I'd be maybe able to attract more students, but I'm not sure I want this. Lastly, institutional web pages at my university are not easily customizable, and to do that I'd have to setup a page somewhere else: though it's surely feasible, it's not something I'm willing to undertake at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I Have two friends who had a similar situation. Here my take on a middle eastern student and a PhD:

1. **"Money Talks" Route**: In most cases you will find a supervisor in an institute that take a student who pays for his/her PhD. If the supervisor is good for you, or you are good for the supervisor's research group is another question; and in fact not the focus here. The fact is that you paid your way into the institute. The outcome here might be a PhD degree however you will not get that much out of it in my opinion; because for example, here in the UK you will spend around 60,000 Pounds for three years of a Ph.D program plus the cost of living, where other students are doing them for free.
2. **Political Scene In Middle East**: Lets be clear here, middle east is filled with incompetent governments, where at any moment, a war might get started. I wouldn't recommend anyone to be a researcher over there, as there is no peace of mind, and priorities for the governments are something else than funding research.
3. **Language Of Research**: The language of research is English. You should learn fluent English to read and write (the harder part). If you do a research in a non English speaking country, like in Egypt, how you would communicate to the world? I see many researchers with very bad English in conferences which is a shame.

**Conclusion**: Take your time and find a PhD in a developed country for a better personal and professional future. If necessary, pay for your PhD program, however somewhere that is worth paying.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why would doing a PhD in Egypt exclude being able to communicate in English? It's a matter of personal development and should most certainly not be an important point to consider when choosing the geographical location of a university.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to join academia in the US or Europe, it would be easiest for you to apply for a PhD there directly, since the competition is less for a PhD position than for say a postdoc.
However, if you are genuinely interested in your field of research and join a good Egyptian group that makes sure you publish quality work, your chances for future employment are not negligible. I guess it must not be easy for a student to judge of the quality of senior researchers. My best tip would be to find a mentor at your university or elsewhere that can help you with that.
You could even contact professors abroad and ask their opinions about this or that group (be diplomatic).

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think that regardless of where you do your PhD, if you are an outstanding student your peer reviewed journal publications will show that. They are a sort of Universal standard, which illustrate your scientific capability. If you can convince world leaders in a field that you are good enough, most universities will want to take you. However, this means that you will be likely to get a postdoctoral fellowship, although you will probably get a lower salary than your native peers, which may be annoying for you. To progress beyond being a research fellow is the difficult part. Only 1% in the UK of applicants make it beyond this point, native or foreign. So you would have to be exceptional. If you are considering a career in academia you probably know all of this anyway, but I thought I would share my thoughts on it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a phd is worth the money and effort depends on what your motivations are for doing one.

I certainly knew people who did many years of post graduate studies because they did not want a job. Well worth it for them.

If you simply want to work at a university then getting a degree and then taking a teaching position may be a better bet.

Depends on the field and institution but often teaching is the literal last thing anyone wants to do.